# Append values of a pandas data frame to a list by if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I've got a pandas df, which has one column with either positive or negative float values:

```
snapshot                        0 (column name)
2018-06-21 00:00:00        -60.18
2018-06-21 00:00:15         43.78
2018-06-21 00:00:30        -22.08
```

Now I want to append the positive values to a list that's called:

```
excessSupply=[]
```

and the negative values to:

```
excessLoad=[]
```

by

```
        for row in self.dfenergyBalance:

        if self.dfenergyBalance['0'] < 0:

            self.excessLoad.append(self.dfenergyBalance['0'])

        else:

            self.excessLoad.append(0)
```

(for excessSupply is the if condition self.dfenergyBalance > 0)

The outcome is a key error of the column name '0'

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: The outcome is [0].

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion no loops (slow) are necessesary, also it seems column name is number `0`:

```
mask = dfenergyBalance[0] < 0

excessSupply = dfenergyBalance.loc[mask, 0].tolist()
excessLoad = dfenergyBalance.loc[~mask, 0].tolist()

print (excessSupply)
[-60.18, -22.08]

print (excessLoad)
[43.78]
```

EDIT:

For list with only `0` by length of positive values:

```
excessLoad = [0] * (~mask).sum()
print (excessLoad)
[0]
```

If need only one list with replaced positive to `0` values:

```
L = np.where(mask, dfenergyBalance[0], 0).tolist()
print (L)
[-60.18, 0.0, -22.08]
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to append zero values to the list in order to keep the number of values equal to dataframe?

Comment: @rude.boy - one possible solution is `excessLoad = [0] * (~mask).sum()`